# How to display ArrayList in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create editable `h:panelGrid`. I created this ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<userdata> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class userdata
    {

        int userid;
        int groupid;
        String specialnumber;
        String username;
        String passwd;
        Date datetochangepasswd;
        String address;
        String stateregion;
        String country;
        String userstatus;
        String telephone;
        Date dateuseradded;
        Date userexpiredate;
        Date dateuserlocked;
        String city;
        String email;
        String description;

        public userdata(int userid, int groupid, String specialnumber, String username, String passwd, Date datetochangepasswd,
                String address, String stateregion, String country, String userstatus, String telephone, Date dateuseradded,
                Date userexpiredate, Date dateuserlocked, String city, String email, String description)
        {

            this.userid = userid;
            this.groupid = groupid;
            this.specialnumber = specialnumber;
            this.username = username;
            this.passwd = passwd;
            this.datetochangepasswd = datetochangepasswd;
            this.address = address;
            this.stateregion = stateregion;
            this.country = country;
            this.userstatus = userstatus;
            this.telephone = telephone;
            this.dateuseradded = dateuseradded;
            this.userexpiredate = userexpiredate;
            this.dateuserlocked = dateuserlocked;
            this.city = city;
            this.email = email;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address)
        {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getCity()
        {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city)
        {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCountry()
        {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country)
        {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public Date getDatetochangepasswd()
        {
            return datetochangepasswd;
        }

        public void setDatetochangepasswd(Date datetochangepasswd)
        {
            this.datetochangepasswd = datetochangepasswd;
        }

        public Date getDateuseradded()
        {
            return dateuseradded;
        }

        public void setDateuseradded(Date dateuseradded)
        {
            this.dateuseradded = dateuseradded;
        }

        public Date getDateuserlocked()
        {
            return dateuserlocked;
        }

        public void setDateuserlocked(Date dateuserlocked)
        {
            this.dateuserlocked = dateuserlocked;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email)
        {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public int getGroupid()
        {
            return groupid;
        }

        public void setGroupid(int groupid)
        {
            this.groupid = groupid;
        }

        public String getPasswd()
        {
            return passwd;
        }

        public void setPasswd(String passwd)
        {
            this.passwd = passwd;
        }

        public String getSpecialnumber()
        {
            return specialnumber;
        }

        public void setSpecialnumber(String specialnumber)
        {
            this.specialnumber = specialnumber;
        }

        public String getStateregion()
        {
            return stateregion;
        }

        public void setStateregion(String stateregion)
        {
            this.stateregion = stateregion;
        }

        public String getTelephone()
        {
            return telephone;
        }

        public void setTelephone(String telephone)
        {
            this.telephone = telephone;
        }

        public Date getUserexpiredate()
        {
            return userexpiredate;
        }

        public void setUserexpiredate(Date userexpiredate)
        {
            this.userexpiredate = userexpiredate;
        }

        public int getUserid()
        {
            return userid;
        }

        public void setUserid(int userid)
        {
            this.userid = userid;
        }

        public String getUsername()
        {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username)
        {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getUserstatus()
        {
            return userstatus;
        }

        public void setUserstatus(String userstatus)
        {
            this.userstatus = userstatus;
        }
    }


    // Getter for the data list
    public ArrayList<userdata> getuserdata(){

        return dataList;
    }
```

I want to display the data into `h:panelGrid`. Can you tell me how I can do this?

I want to create [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-update-row-in-jsf-datatable/) editable table but with `h:panelGrid`. I suppose that it's possible to use `h:panelGrid` instead `h:dataTable`?

Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may be actually possible to hack something with `h:panelGrid`, you probably would have to fiddle with a lot of unnecessary code in your MBs, just for creating and binding components.

If you want a finer grained control for your HTML table, what you want to do is probably to use `ui:repeat`, something like this:

```
<table>
    <ui:repeat var="elem" value="#{yourMB.yourDataList}">
        <tr>
            <td>#{elem.userid}</td>
            <td>
               <h:outputText value="#{elem.name}" 
                    rendered="#{not elem.editable}" />
               <h:inputText value="#{elem.name}" rendered="#{elem.editable}" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <h:outputText value="#{elem.telephone}" 
                    rendered="#{not elem.editable}" />
               <h:inputText value="#{elem.telephone}"
                            rendered="#{elem.editable}" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h:commandLink value="Edit" rendered="#{not elem.editable}"
                 action="#{yourMB.editAction(elem)}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
<h:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="#{yourMB.saveAction}" />
```

For this to work you should have a backing bean looking like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class YourMB {
    private List<Elem> dataList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // initialize dataList here
    }
    public void editAction(Elem e) {
        e.setEditable(true);
    }
    public void saveAction() {
        // do your thing here to update in the database,
        // and then reset the editable property for all items:
        for (Elem e : dataList) {
            e.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
    // getters and setters...
}
```

Check out [the tutorials available here](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Looping), which teaches how to use `ui:repeat` and also presents other options for looping in JSF.

Comment: How I can implement this editable table: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-update-row-in-jsf-datatable/ using your code example?

Comment: You would have to use a `@ViewScoped` bean, and bind `h:inputText` components to the values of the datalist. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: I've updated the answer, exemplifying how you would go about doing that same editable thing in your page. You need to have a property `editable` in your model and implement the action methods just like in the tutorial for the `h:dataTable`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But just in case I will look for other similar solutions.