# How to rewrite JSF h:table into h:panelGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need a way to create editable table like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-update-row-in-jsf-datatable/). I interested is it possible to use `h:panelGrid` to display and edit the data. From my previews [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675369/how-to-display-arraylist-in-jsf-page) I saw that it's possible to simple JSF table, but is this possible with `h:panelGrid`?

```
<table>
    <ui:repeat var="elem" value="#{yourMB.yourDataList}">
        <tr>
            <td>#{elem.userid}</td>
            <td>
               <h:outputText value="#{elem.name}" 
                    rendered="#{not elem.editable}" />
               <h:inputText value="#{elem.name}" rendered="#{elem.editable}" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <h:outputText value="#{elem.telephone}" 
                    rendered="#{not elem.editable}" />
               <h:inputText value="#{elem.telephone}"
                            rendered="#{elem.editable}" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h:commandLink value="Edit" rendered="#{not elem.editable}"
                 action="#{yourMB.editAction(elem)}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
<h:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="#{yourMB.saveAction}" />
```

Comment: The problem with trying to do it using [`h:panelGrid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGrid.html) is that you can't iterate through a list inside it. `h:panelGrid` is more like a container where you arrange UI widgets, and `ui:repeat` and `h:dataTable` are the ones appropriate for iterating through a list/collection.

Comment: Why exactly do you need `h:panelGrid` instead of `h:dataTable`?

Comment: The answer to your concrete (and rhetorical) question is just "no" and already answered in a basic JSF book/tutorial or at least by just logically thinking. Is a bounty really needed for that? To better understand your strange question so that a better answer than just "no" can be posted, I have posted the above comment with a sensible contra-question which you never gave feedback on for some reason. What exactly do you want?

Comment: You can try inplace component from primefaces
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/inplace.jsf

Comment: If you're trying to use JSF to loop over data and build up a table manually then you are really missing the boat with reference to its Component basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "NO". Try to use h:dataTable instead of h:panelGrid.